# Possible to stream part of a file from mongo with node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, gridfs

I see how I can create a readable stream for a file in GridFS in Node.js using the native mongo driver. However, I'm writing a server that responds to byte range requests, so I'd like to only stream back part of the file. What's the best way to do this? Should I just implement my own read stream that pulls data from the database in chunks? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the stream does not support arbitrary starting points so you'll have to implement your own that seeks into the correct chunk and then streams from there.